# how to delete specific number of rows using jquery provided by argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a sample code. This will delete entire row if nor args provided. If provided it will delete the given rows.

```
function deleteTableRows(tableID)
{
    rowsToDel = document.getElementById('getrows').value;
    if(document.getElementById(tableID) !== undefined)
    {
        var tbl = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var deleteAll = false;
        if(rowsToDel ==null || rowsToDel == "")
        {
            rowsToDel = tbl.rows.length;
            deleteAll = true;
        }
        if(deleteAll)
        {
            while(rowsToDel > 0)
            {
                tbl.deleteRow(rowsToDel - 1);
                rowsToDel = tbl.rows.length;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(rowsToDel > 0)
            {
                tbl.deleteRow(rowsToDel - 1);
                rowsToDel = rowsToDel - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to do this in jquery

Answer (score 0):

[**See a working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vjFm/1)

```
function deleteTableRows(table, rowsToDelete) {
    table = $(table);
    var rows = table.find('> tbody > tr');
    rows.slice(-(rowsToDelete || rows.length)).remove();
}
```

Moved the `rowsToDelete` parameter inside the function to remove the external dependency on the `#getrows` element.

Also, changed the `table` parameter so we can pass the DOM element, or a selector, or a jQuery wrapped object to select which table.